# How do I completely re-install my PC with only Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I have windows 7 and ubuntu on my computer. The problem is that I only have a few memory on ubuntu because of windows so I want to erase windows from my computer and only run with ubuntu. How?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows

Comment: Exactly use the OS-Uninstaller. Will update your grub neatly as well.

Answer (score 1):

- Install a partition manager. Gparted is one option in Ubuntu (`sudo apt-get install gparted` if not already installed; or check Ubuntu software center).
- Open Gparted and delete the partition(s) marked as "Windows". If you have a C: and D: on W7 there will be 2 partitions.

  Mind you: you might have a recovery partition. It would be best to leave that alone just in case.
- Format the partitions you deleted as ext4 and give them a mountpoint. These partitions will then automatically show up as empty disks in Nautilus (or your Desktop if set as showing them there).
- You will need to `chown` the disks to your user with `sudo chown $USER:$USER {/mountpoint}`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to make a backup of all of your files, and then simply reinstall Ubuntu from scratch, when it asks you where you want to install ubuntu just say "Erase everything and Install Ubuntu"

This will completely remove Windows from your computer and you will only have Ubunutu installed.

Best, 
Lev